# How to use docx4js for parsing pasted data from microsoft word

Tags: javascript, parsing, ms-word, docx4js

In the [docx4js GitHub page](https://github.com/lalalic/docx4js) it is illustrated how to open a docx file and parse it. Is it possible to use this library to parse clipboard data obtained from copying some part of ms-word docx?

**PS 1**I think that this library is a node application for server-side use, but I want to use it in client-side!

**PS 2**: I partially wrote some parser for this purpose but there are many different types of structure and styling and this task is rather complicated and error prone! Is there any (javascript) library simplifying this parsing?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612488/2281751) is related to this question!