# Microsoft word clipboard HTML documentation

Tags: parsing, ms-word, doc

I could not find any documentation describing conventions in `text/html` data in the clipboard resulting from copying part of a word document!

Specifically I want to know what classes like `MsoNormal, TableGrid313, MsoTableGrid, MsoHeading9, MsoListParagraph` are there! Or does styling information of texts always lay in `style` attribute of a span element containing the text?

Comment: The Word round-tip HTML is undocumented as it's not an official Word file format. It was created to enable round-tripping Word documents for viewing (and some editing) in a browser, many years ago. Even then, it was not documented as its use was for internal Microsoft software. Being HTML, anyone could read and produce it, but MS made an conscious decision to not document it (and not need to put the resources into maintaining that documentation).

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your very useful comment. I think this can be considered as an answer to my question!

Comment: OK, I'll put it in an answer as I can't find any Answer at all on the site that is a duplicate. Funny, I thought there was, but I must have written that as a comment, as well, some time in the past...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Word round-tip HTML is undocumented as it's not an official Word file format.

It was created to enable round-tripping Word documents for viewing (and some editing) in a browser, many years ago. Even then, it was not documented as its use was for internal Microsoft software. Being HTML, anyone could read and produce it, but MS made an conscious decision to not document it (and not need to put the resources into maintaining that documentation).